# How in Laravel access to relation while building a query?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have tables

**companies** id | name 
**guests**    id | name 
**books**     id | name

They have models with relations 
Company -> hasMany -> Guest 
Guest   -> hasMany -> Book

Now, I wanna get all books where guests from particular company
I have no Idea how to reach that in eloquent ORM
I will apreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty standard procedure with eloquent. There are a lot of tutorials on the internet explain this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm stuck in building a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to query based on the existence of relationships:

```
$books = Book::whereHas('guest.company', function ($query) use ($companyId) {
    $query->where('id', $companyId);
})->get();
```

Roughly: get all books that belong to a guest that belongs to a company with id of `$companyId`

[Laravel Docs - 5.6 - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 0):

`$company = Company::with("guests.books")->find($id);` // or how you get the company doesn't matter

`$company->guests->books` // gives you what you're looking for.

Note that, `with("guests.books")`is not necessary but, it provides you all data in single query

For more further you may want to check out [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) about relationships

Comment: I'm getting exception that books doesn't exist

Comment: $items = Company::with("guests.books")->find(2);
print_r($items->guests->books);die;

Comment: Could you edit your question and share your models ?